# How Are Experienced Web Developers Deploying Django Into Production on EC2?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have never actually worked for a company which is deploying a Django App (with a large user base), and am curious about what is the best way to do this.

Right now I am hosting a Django App on EC2. The code for the app is sitting in my github account. I have nginx serving static content, and behind it a single apache server running django + mod_wsgi.

I am trying to figure out what the best practice is for "continuous deployment". Right now, after I have added additional functionality I do the following on EC2:

1) git reset HEAD --hard

2) git pull

3) restart apache

4) restart nginx

I have custom logic in my settings.py file so that if I am running on EC2, debug gets set to False, and my databases switch from sqlite3 (development) to mysql (production).

This seems to be working for me now, but I am wondering what is wrong with this process and how could I improve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've worked with systems that use [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html) to deploy to multiple servers

Comment: +1 fabric makes deployment logic repeatable, versionable, and keeps it simple

Comment: seems like fabric is the way to go. i will check it out this weekend. thanks for your help guys (everyone below included)

Answer (score 2):

I'm the former lead developer at [The Texas Tribune](http://texastribune.org), which is 100% Django. We deployed to EC2 using [RightScale](http://www.rightscale.com/). I didn't personally write the deployment scripts, but it allowed us to get new instances into the rotation very, very quickly and scales on-demand. it's not cheap, but was worth every penny in my opinion.

Comment: thanks. i will chekc this out also, although i am looking for a free solution if possible

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with John and say that [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html) is the tool to do this sort of thing comfortably. You probably don't want to configure git to automatically deploy with a post commit hook, but you might want to configure a fabric command to run your test suite locally, and then push to production if it passes.

Many people run separate dev and production settings files, rather than having custom logic in there to detect if it's in a production environment. You can inherit from a unified file, and then override the bits that are different between dev and production. Then you start the server using the production file, rather than relying on a single unified settings.py.

If you're just using apache to host the application, you might benefit from a lighter weight solution. Using fastcgi with nginx would allow you to do away with the overhead of apache entirely. There's also a wsgi module for nginx, but I don't know if it's production ready at this point.

Comment: What is the benefit of eliminating apache entirely? I could imagine it might speed up requests because they would not be redirected to a different port via nginx (maybe)? I was under the impression that apache is a much more mature product compared to nginx, and that is why people continue to use it?

Comment: Apache is a more featureful product, which is why people continue to use it. Eliminating unnecessary layers in your stack is a good way to improve speed, and side by side, nginx murders apache for tasks that it can do. User configurable .htaccess is probably the most common reason people keep apache. Lowering memory usage is another reason to eliminate apache.

Comment: Also, if you've already got nginx in your stack, I'm not clear on the "mature product" comment. If nginx fails, it's not like apache will step in and take over.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more good way how to manage this. For ubuntu/debian amis it is good to manager versions and do deployemnts by packeging your application into .deb

Comment: im using ubuntu? i am a bit confused about the benefits of this?

Comment: I'm not sure using you ubuntu or some other aims.
Benefit can be in easy code management, you can manage merging of config options, automatically manage dependencies. Can run pre/post.. install scripts for updating configurations/database etc.

Comment: This is a horrible idea. This is simply not how people deploy Python and Django projects. We use pip and virtualenv, and south for migrations.

Comment: I think this depends on project, in many cases this must be done as a part of the project.

Comment: @PaulMcMillan Just because it's "simply not how people deploy Python and Django projects" doesn't mean it's a horrible idea. Elitist attitudes such as that hinder progress, potentially productive discussion, and innovation.

Comment: @Codygman 2 years later, after spending a year doing python debian packaging for work, I still don't like doing it that way (but admit my earlier comment was too harsh). It's perhaps appropriate if the rest of the deployed infrastructure has custom configuration in debian packages, but it's not ideal for individual python deployments and I can't recommend starting down that path if you have a fresh choice.